# how to http POST to a web form using C++ /MFC?

Tags: c++, forms, web

I use CInternetSession with GetHttpConnection, but I can't find anywhere a good info on how to fill and post a web form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165298) explains how to simulate a POST request using `CInternetSession`.

The included sample code goes like this:

```
CString strHeaders = _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// URL-encoded form variables -
// name = "John Doe", userid = "hithere", other = "P&Q"
CString strFormData = _T("name=John+Doe&userid=hithere&other=P%26Q");

CInternetSession session;
CHttpConnection *pConnection = session.GetHttpConnection(_T("ServerNameHere"));
CHttpFile *pFile = pConnection->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST,
    _T("FormActionHere"));
BOOL result = pFile->SendRequest(strHeaders, (LPVOID) (LPCTSTR) strFormData,
    strFormData.GetLength());
```

Comment: And how can I read the reponse page which is sent back by web server?

Comment: It will be available in `pFile`. You can use its `Read()` and `ReadString()` methods to extract it.

Comment: After posting I get return code 200 which is ok, and then if I read the pFile I get a missing page result

Comment: Do you mean you get IIS's standard `404` error page with a `200` status code? [This can happen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4996874/464709) in some circumstances. Are you perchance submitting your request to an ASP.NET page or handler? Is the web server under your control?

Comment: Hi,
  Yes I get the IIS 404 error page with the 200 status code.
  The web page is an ASP.NET 4 page and yes the server is under my control.

Comment: Then it would be interesting to know if this behavior is the result of a call to `TransferRequest()` (potentially meaning it's a legitimate response to your query) or if it comes from an unhandled exception of some kind. The `Application` event log on the server should contain entries about those, you might want to give it a look.

Comment: Hi, There is no entry in the event viewer application log, I don't have a transferrequest yet, I have a label on the form page to display the received content for debugging until I get this working.

Comment: Since you're posting to a page, maybe that's a view state problem. Can you update your question with the server-side code of your page, and the client C++ code you wrote from this answer? We might be able to help further then.